# Eclipse Scala IDE won't start

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am trying to download Eclipse Scala IDE [here](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html) for Mac (Big Sur), but when I try to open it, it gives an error message and tells me to view the log file.

Here is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Here is the output of the log file.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-10-15 15:50:52.671
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSGraphicsContext.graphicsPort()" because "graphicsContext" is null
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.initializeDialogUnits(Dialog.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Comment: The **ScalaIDE** project has been deprecated and abandoned since a couple of years now. Use **IntelliJ** or **metals** instead. If you prefer **Eclipse** you can integrate it with **metals**

Comment: Got it, thanks. They should really make a note on their website...

Comment: That code is based on Eclipse 4.7 which is too old to run on macOS 11